# Navigation Drawer Activity overlaps my content

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I've chosen a Navigation Drawer Activity for my project.

I am going to use Fragments in this project. When I try to show my fragment the toolbar overlaps onto my fragment content.

I'm pretty sure it's a problem with my xml, but not sure where.
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My content_main.xml contains an empty frame layout so I can add fragments using transactions. My fragment content shows up, but top part is hidden by toolbar.

Comment: do you use any view pager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to arrange it such that the "content_main.xml" (which has your fragment 
container) is **"include**-ed" in "app_bar_main.xml".

Code:

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Created for MainActivity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Created for MainActivity -->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <!--
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
    -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Created for MainActivity -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <!-- 
        Now, just attach your "fragment"(s) to above view with "id = fragment_container"
    -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

include content main in app_bar_main.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="bd.tahsincom.smartsell.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main2">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

here in a new layout write your code that u want to display default on opening the app and set its **visibility="visible"**!!

content_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/strtlayID"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"

 android:visibility="visible">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/canada"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="This is safety application for women's. "/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

here set the layout **li.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);** where u get the id of selected fragment!

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
                implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            Fragment fragment,ff=null;
            LinearLayout li;
        int pre;
            Class fragmentClass = null;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                li=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.strtlayID);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();


                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
                toggle.syncState();

                NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            }

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {
                Fragment fragment = null;



li.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                switch (itemId) {
                    case R.id.nav_start:

                        fragment = new start_app();
                        pre=R.id.nav_start;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_word:
                        fragment = new word_act();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_setting:
                        fragment = new setting();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_faq:
                        fragment = new Faq();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_logout:
                        fragment = new Logout();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_share:
                        fragment = new Share();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_send:
                        fragment = new Sens();
                        break;
                }
                if (fragment != null) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    //ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter,R.anim.exit,R.anim.pop_enter,R.anim.pop_exit);
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                    ft.commit();
                }


                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());

                return true;
            }
        }
```